# MongoDB creating, finding from and changing an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here's what I want to achieve in mongodb but as a javascript example.

```
var array = [];

//Initiating an array
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
array[i] = 0;
}

//Changing a value at an index
array[14] = 1;

//Getting a value at an index
console.log(array[4]);

//Swapping Two Variables.
var temp = array[14];
array[14] = array[12];
array[12] = temp;
```

So far I can set a schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
array: {Number: Number, Value: Number}
});
```

I can Initiate it later on

```
schema.statics.name = function(cb) {
var new = new Array({
{Number: 1, Value: 0},
{Number: 2, Value: 0},
...
{Number: 30, Value: 0}
});
 new.save();
```

I can loop through them all

```
c.user.array.forEach(function (element) {
console.log(element.Number);
console.log(element.Value);
})
```

But I get stuck with finding a single value or setting/switching them.

It seems overly complicated for something so simple in a programming language; ive been trying for the last few hours and there so many {} and $'s that its making my head hurt.

From what I can find I should be using .find() but then there no examples of how the stuff in the schema is laid out.

Comment: Woah there, you can't name variables `new`. That's a reserved word.

Comment: Also, you simply might want to read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html, I have a feeling that most of your confusion comes from trying out stuff without reading the docs.

Comment: Ah yeah it's pseudo I'm not actually using those names :P I'll get reading thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema:

```
array: [{value: Number}]
```

Can be initialised as many times as you want:

```
backpack: [{value: 0}, {value:0}, {value:0}]
```

and can be accessed like

```
.array[1].value
```

[more info on sub docs and children](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Thanks to Tomalak